# Let's get critical: Dec 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Linguistics Stack Exchange](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: So this is closed now? The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) link now gives a 404. There appear to have been one review. Does this mean that we do all love L.SE? And why these ten?

Comment: @jlawler Hello, the link should give you a page now (it does to me) saying that the evaluation is over. That's because the evaluation is done now and then. Not continuously... :) The one review means that only one user took the time to do it. I don't remember if there are criteria for the questions that are taken into the review or if it's totally random... Hope that helps.

Comment: OK, so it's basically totally random, then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [What are these NPs, syntactically and semantically?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4784/what-are-these-nps-syntactically-and-semantically)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Do any languages have half-voiced affricates?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4792/do-any-languages-have-half-voiced-affricates)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Does Mandarin Chinese have phonetically voiced plosives, fricatives, or affricates (besides "r" = [ʐ] / [ɻ])?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4860/does-mandarin-chinese-have-phonetically-voiced-plosives-fricatives-or-affricat)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Etymology of witness in Hebrew](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4814/etymology-of-witness-in-hebrew)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Why doesn't the subject prevent WH- extraction of an internal argument?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4828/why-doesnt-the-subject-prevent-wh-extraction-of-an-internal-argument)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Has a spoken language ever borrowed a word from a signed language?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4837/has-a-spoken-language-ever-borrowed-a-word-from-a-signed-language)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Is there a formal classification of types of word origins?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/5916/is-there-a-formal-classification-of-types-of-word-origins)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Linguistic relation Turkish dada English dad](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4791/linguistic-relation-turkish-dada-english-dad)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Arabic Diacritization List](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4801/arabic-diacritization-list)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Help with syntax trees for sentences](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/5883/help-with-syntax-trees-for-sentences)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

Comment: Only a single person took the survey. :(